# Starting an activity when tapping on a widget

Tags: android, android-activity, android-widget

I'm developing an android widget and i would like to start a certain activity when i tap on a certain area of my widget, and another one when tapping somewhere else.
How can i do this ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 2 Linear Layouts in places wherever you want to touch, and let them be blank (No child).

Then add `android:clickable = "true"` in linear layouts. and now add clicklisteners to thes two layouts and start Activity..

Something like this..

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutId);

layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

protected void onClick(View v){
//start Activity

}

});
```

Comment: Thanks! ok, where should i add the click listeners ? can you give me an short example ?

Comment: @maephisto ..  in which ever Activity you want to touch... I mean from the Activity from where you want start other Activities..

Comment: I'm sure he means app (homescreen) widgets? Is that even possible?

Comment: Thanks! still i have an issue : where should i place that piece of code - i only have a AppWidgetProvider class, where i cannot use the findViewById